# How to make TeXLive download and install the necessary files?

Tags: texlive, input-encodings, linux, tlmgr, update

I am working with TeXLive 2021 in Linux Mint (English version). I need to work with Russian texts. I started from the file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

There are some errors when compiling the file via `latex main.tex`:

```
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `t2aenc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
! LaTeX Error: Encoding scheme `T2A' unknown.
! LaTeX Error: File `cp1251.def' not found.
```

What I tried:

- `tlmgr update --all` (hoping it will download all the necessary files...). This command made an error with checksum -5. I read a lot about it and used some advises but nothings changed.
- `texliveonfly main.tex` -- I also hoped it would download the necessary files but the compilation errors are the same.
- tried to find `cp1251.def` and `t2aenc.def` over the Internet and on the PC with Windows with MikTeX where all works -- I did not succeed.

I wanted to make my LaTeX system on-the-fly-like so that all the necessary packages and files are downloaded automatically (as it was in MikTeX in Windows). So the local problem is language and encoding and the global one is to make the system auto-updatable.

Comment: well if tlmgr errors you will have to handle this first. Then you can install with `tlmgr install cyrillic`.

Comment: Exactly how did you install texlive? If from mint, it us unlikely you can use `tlmgr` to install latex packages as the Linux fits wants you to install from them instead. You can use `apt-file`  to learn which debian package provides the latex files you need

Comment: @daleif I downloaded the archive install-tl-unx.tar.gz from https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html and made ```perl install-tl```. Then I typed ```sudo apt install latex-basic```. LaTeX files in English are compiled okay.

Comment: What exactly is `latex-basic`? never heard of that before. After running the install-tl did you update your path to include the newly installed texlive?

Comment: After the very install, I typed in terminal ```latex myfile.tex```. I was said there wasn't a latex program but I can install it using the command above. I can confuse the name -- maybe, it was latex-base or something like this. I followed the instructions in the terminal. No, I did not changed the PATH variable after the installation. But right now I have added the path to ```/usr/local/texlive/2021```

Comment: Then now you have two latex installations, the so-called upstream one installed via install-tl and one from mint. My guess is that the tlmgr you got was from mint and that one is crippled. You need to prepend the proper path to the binaries to your normal path. Note that the path you mentioned is not the full binary path it should also include `bin/arch` where arch is whatever is suitable for your system.

Comment: did you put /usr/local/texlive before or after /usr/bin in your PATH? as you have installed two separate tex systems you will get one or the other depending on your path. what does `which latex` report as the location of the tex binary ?

Comment: you installed tex from TUG then as you did not set the PATH the latex command was not found so linux mint suggested that you install latex from the linux mint repositories using apt, but that is a different tex. You can use either but you need to know which one you are using. The system one you update using apt, the one fron tug you update using tlmgr

Comment: Ah, now I understand! There are two LaTeX's. I am new to Linux and TeXLive and did not expect all this stuff... Moreover, before reading @daleif and @DavidCarlisle, I have yet installed MikTeX for Linux and this one have packages auto-installation. I made ```initexmf --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1``` for it. The ```which latex``` says: ```/usr/local/bin/latex```. With MiKTeX my files are compiled okay. Anyway, TeXLive occurred difficult for me to deal with...

Comment: Now add  TinyTeX to grow the mess of LaTeX distros ... Seriously, install only that from TUG, add the path to `/etc/environment` and that is all. It should be some like  `PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux: ...` where `...`  are all the paths that you already have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the people who commented above, the problem is solved. I have removed both MikTeX and Kpathsea LaTeX (libkpathsea) and left only one TeXLive. Then I added the path `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux` to the PATH variable. Then I did `tlmgr update --all`. It works now.